# Position element based on :after content

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the `content` parameter of the `:after` psuedo-element to display text for a group of radio buttons. However this is causing everything to overlap.

I would like to find a way to add some padding or use the margin of the `:after` content, however not sure if that's possible.

Is there a way to position something based on the `content` parameter of the `:after` psuedo-element of the previous element?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9y959azg/

**HTML**

```
<form id="ValidateForm">
<label for="AgentId">Agent Id</label>
<input id="AgentId" name="AgentId" type="text" >
<label for="LOB">LOB</label>
<input id="Retirement" name="LOB" type="radio" value="R"> 
<input id="Life" name="LOB" type="radio" value="L"> 
<input id="Business" name="LOB" type="radio" value="B">     
<label for="SignDate">Application Sign Date</label>
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Application Sign Date must be a date." id="SignDate" name="SignDate" type="text" value="">
<input type="button" value="Go">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
    #ValidateForm{
        margin: 10px 10px 5px 0;
    }

    #ValidateForm label{
        font-weight: bold;
        float:left;
        clear:left;
        min-width:250px;
        margin:inherit; 
    }

    #ValidateForm label.required:after {
      content:"*";
      color:red;
    }

    #ValidateForm input{
        float:left;
        margin: inherit;
    }

    #ValidateForm .submission-attempted input:invalid { 
        background-color: #f9b2b2; 
        outline: none; 
    }

    #ValidateForm input[type=button]{
        clear:left;
    }

    #ValidateForm input[type=radio]:after {
        margin: 0 20px 0;
    }

    #ValidateForm input#Retirement:after {
        content:"Retirement";
    }

    #ValidateForm input#Life:after {
        content:"Life";
    }

    #ValidateForm input#Business:after {
        content:"Business";
    }
```

Comment: I tried to play around with it in your fiddle example but I don't think it is going to work. I would suggest instead of using the css content rather just iterate through them using Jquery's each function. For example:

    $('input[radio]').each(function(){
        $(this).after('<span>Something</span>');
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set width at the  **input[type=radio]**

```
#ValidateForm input[type=radio]{
    width: 80px !important;
}
```

or

```
#ValidateForm input[type=radio]{
    margin-right: 80px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is still only setting the margin according to the box model of the radio button, not the content in the `:after` element

Comment: then, it beyond CSS could do, you need to use javascript to help.

Answer (score 0):

try set margin for the element to create enought place ...  i think  :after content is referencing (calculate position relative to) element not DOM